# Efficiently loop over a pair of lists to compare elements

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists. One of them is a list of lists. More specifically:

```
lst1 = [[4, 5, 6], [19, 20, 24, 25]]
lst2 = [8, 21]
```

The numbers of each list list represent **indices**.

What I want to do is to remove any element from `lst2`
which is not in-between the indices of each list in `lst1`.

For example, number **8** from `lst2` should be removed because it is not between the first and the last number of both lists (elements) of `lst1`. Number 21 should not be removed cause it is between the first and last element of the second list (element) of `lst2`.

The code I have written so far is:

```
for elem2 in lst2:
    count = 0
    for elem1 in lst1:
        minsubelem = min(elem1)
        maxsubelem = max(elem1)
                
        condition = not ((elem2 > minsubelem) and (elem2 < maxsubelem))
        
        if condition:
            count += 1
            
    if count == len(lst1):
        index = lst2.index(elem2)
        lst2.pop(index)

print(lst2)
```

Which returns:

```
[21]
```

This works but as you can imagine using 2 for loops it's not that optimal and if the lists are long the computation time may increase significantly.

What shall be a potential replacent for this code in order to be more efficient?

Clarifications:

1. The indices in `lst2` **are never equal** to any of the indices in
   `lst1`.
2. I have read the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) documentation but probably I am
   lacking the experience to link the proposed methods to my use case.

Comment: It's not the two loops that are the problem; you're going to _have_ to iterate over both lists to get the information you need. An issue is that you're iterating over `lst1` as many times as there are elements in `lst2`. Think about how you can only iterate over `lst1` once.

Comment: A slight optimisation is that if you ever find a min and max that contains `elem2`, then you could quit the inner loop knowing that `elem2` does not have to be removed from `lst2`. Also, you should not modify `lst2` while you are iterating over it. Perhaps best to make a new list of all the surviving elements.

Comment: @Ben that's a part of what I am thinking of :) . I thought maybe I could use sets but there will never be the same number occurrence between the elements of lists in lst1 and elements of lst2. I am reading the itertools documentation cause somehow I suspect there should be some function assisting this use case but I can't link it yet.

Comment: @quamrana that is why I use the count variable to ensure that the number is removed after chacking the condition for all lists in lst1. Actually I am saving the survived in a new list but ideally I would like to avoid the allocation/creation of a new list.

Comment: That's what I'm saying: You are always checking the condition for all lists. There will be times when you don't have to check all the lists. Once you find a reason for the element to stay, it can be saved and you can skip checking the other lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're guaranteed that the sub-lists in `lst1` will be sorted, then you don't need to look for the minimum and maximum of each sub-list. Just grab the first and last elements of each sub-list, and use those as your min and max. Also, in general, it's far easier and cleaner to retain desirable elements rather than purging undesirable ones - instead of popping elements you don't want, just build a new list, retaining only those elements you do want:

```
lst1 = [[4, 5, 6], [19, 20, 24, 25]]
lst2 = [8, 21]

def predicate(value):
    return any(l[0] < value < l[-1] for l in lst1)

print(list(filter(predicate, lst2)))
```

Output:

```
[21]
>>>
```

---

EDIT - To address your concern of not being able to use `filter` (because you would need to pass your `lst1` as an argument to `predicate`), you could use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

lst1 = [[4, 5, 6], [19, 20, 24, 25]]
lst2 = [8, 21]

def predicate(value, ranges):
    return any(l[0] < value < l[-1] for l in ranges)

print(list(filter(partial(predicate, ranges=lst1), lst2)))
```

Note, that in the end this is still basically equivalent to using two loops. One "loop" iterates over all the items in `lst2`, invoking the predicate on each one, and the other loop iterates over every sub-list in `lst1` (called `ranges` in `predicate`). You do get an early-out, though, thanks to the short-circuit evaluation which takes place in `any`.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion! However, imagine that here for the sake of simplicity I manually created the lst1 and lst2. In your suggestion, predicate function "knows" lst1 which is not the case for me. In other words, I need to include lst1 somehow in the needed arguments of your predicate function and this means I probably can't use the filter function cause predicate needs 2 arguments.

Comment: In addition, sub-lists are always sorted.

Comment: I found how to overcome the issue I have stated above regarding the arguments of the filter function. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609935/passing-a-function-with-two-arguments-to-filter-in-python) helped me. It can be combined with the partial function from functools.

Comment: @wannabedatasth I've edited my question - take a look.

Comment: isn't the time complexity of this sol is O(n^2) ?. 'any' will return a generator object so if the value is the range it'll return. It's just like adding a break in nested for loop. Am I missing anything here? @PaulM.

Comment: @Nk03 No, you're not missing anything. That's exactly right.

Answer (score 0):

One pass over list one to get the min and max values and abstracting the rest away into pandas. No idea about performance though.

```
import pandas as pd 

lst1 = [[4, 5, 6], [19, 20, 24, 25]]
lst2 = [8, 21]

lst1_min_max = [[min(x), max(x)] for x in lst1]
lst1_min_max_df = pd.DataFrame(lst1_min_max, columns=['min', 'max'])
lst1_min_max_df['key'] = 1

lst12_df = pd.DataFrame(lst2, columns=['values_to_check'])
lst12_df['key'] = 1

lst1_min_max_df_join = lst1_min_max_df.merge(lst12_df, how='inner')

lst1_min_max_df_join['value_to_check_in_range'] = lst1_min_max_df_join['values_to_check'].between(lst1_min_max_df_join['min'], lst1_min_max_df_join['max'])

res = lst1_min_max_df_join.groupby('values_to_check')['value_to_check_in_range'].any()
list(res.index[res.values])
```

Comment: Thank you @M.Hahn for your suggestion! I actually thought of doing that. However, the list examples I provided are simplified. For the scale of my use case I think I would prefer to avoid the transformation to pandas. 
Your suggestion comes in handy in different situaitons where you're already working with pandas.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a whitelist, and then just check if the number in lst 2 is in the white list. Since the indices in lst2 are never equal you could even further reduce the entries in the whitelist by using `range(l[0]+1, l[-1])` if the ranged in lst0 can overlap you could reduce duplciates by using a white-set instead of list.

```
lst0 = [[4, 5, 6], [19, 20, 24, 25]]
lst1 = [i for l in lst0 for i in list(range(l[0]+1, l[-1]))]
lst2 = [8, 21]

print([n for n in lst2 if n in lst1])
#[21]
```

Comment: Thank you @Andreas for the reply! However, doesn't your suggestion runs 2 for loops again ?